# Why is there never a tan2?

Tags: math

The function `atan2` accepts 2 variables `x` and `y` so it can return an angle of a range of `2pi` instead of `pi`. But why is there never `tan2` which is then the exact opposite of `atan2` and returns 2 values `x` and `y` based on the given angle? Is there a simpler method to get the directional vector of an angle I'm missing?

Comment: How about `sin` and `cos`?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too - is there someting I'm missing here?

Comment: There is such a function and it can be done. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deep reason is probably because FORTRAN functions return a single value.

Indeed, `y= sin(x)`, `x= cos(x)` is what you need. (Alternatively, `y= r * sin(x)`, `x= r * cos(x)` allows you to provide a vector length.)

This lack is a frustration for both users and implementors, because it is quite frequent to need both values at the same time, while this would allow optimizing away some common computations.

Comment: Very good point! The question is not C related, however that probably is the historical reason. Besides that, I always found the function name `atan2` a bit awkward.

Comment: It's worth noting that compilers are good at optimizing `x=cos(t);y=sin(t);` into a single SINCOS instruction on architectures which include it.

Comment: @Sneftel: Ooops, my bad (influenced by reversal of x and y). I'm fixing that. And I agree about SINCOS.

Comment: @Codor: candidate alternatives could be arg, phase, angle, polar_angle, affix_angle, azimuth...

Comment: @Codor: I have changed my mind: FORTRAN ATAN2 was there in the first place, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Well tan2 dosent exist because there isnt a single value of x and y that satisfies tan (theta) since tan is the ratio of opposite by adjacent.

Let us say that tan2 did exist
Then tan2 (60°) would return

```
opp=sqrt (3)    &    adj=1
```

Since tan(60°)= opp/adj = sqrt (3)

But it could also return

```
opp=3           &    adj=sqrt (3)
```

And that would also be equal to sqrt (3);

Since tan is a ratio it returns only one value , that is
The ratio of opposide to adjacent

And also in most programming languages  a function can return only one value

Comment: The natural convention would be to return x and y such that their 2-norm was 1 (such as cos/sin do).

Answer (score 2):

The function

```
t => { cos(t), sin(t) }
```

would be such a function; however it would not be 'the inverse' function of `atan2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need both `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` for the same `x` and you want to compute it efficiently, there is a GNU extension in glibc:

```
void sincos(double x, double *sin, double *cos);
```

see the [`sincos()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sincos) in `math.h`.

To go a step further, if gcc recognizes that you need both `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` but compute them in the naive way, that is, with 2 function calls, it will generate code that only calls `sincos()`. I find that pretty neat.